# Apostrophe character in an html email not showing

Tags: c#, html-email, html-encode, system.net.mail

I am using System.Net.Mail and I am reading html into the body of email.

Unfortunately the apostrophe character `'` is shown as a question mark with a black background.

I have tried to replace the apostrophe with the html `&apos;` but this still displays the question mark with a black background. Other Html tags (h1, p etc) are working fine.

I now there must be a really obvious answer but I cannot seem to find it. Thanks for your help.

UPDATE

It appears that it is System.IO.StreamReader that is causing my problem.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("/Email/Welcome.htm"))
{
     body = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
     //body string now has odd question mark character instead of apostrophe.
}
```

Comment: Looks like an encoding issue to me ...

Comment: I am not doing any encoding myself. Just reading in a .htm file that contains the text and mark up. The apostrophes in the .htm file look fine when opened in Chrome, IE, and Firefox

Comment: Maybe it is `´` not `'` (+ an encoding problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the [encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) of your file you will want to pass that to your [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8xxf0x5.aspx) initialization:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("/Email/Welcome.htm", "Windows-1252"))
{
     body = reader.ReadToEnd();
     // If the encoding is correct you'll now see ´ rather than �
     // Which, by the way is the unicode replacement character
     // See: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save this file as unicode utf-8 format to get it right.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it didn't work. I have updated my question with exactly where I am getting the problem.